# Audio-Interface to computer - multiple separate channels

Tags: mixer, daw, audio-interfaces, multichannel

I know this might be too broad or too subjective, but I'm hitting a wall here.

I record short videos from time to time and also produce music.
I bought a Behringer Xenyx X1222USB to use the additional channels it provides.
Sadly I don't know a whole lot about FX Sends and AUX sends, so I played around with the routing trying to get it to work as I want it to.

**Do all USB Interfaces work with a stereo mix?** It seems that way to me.

**What audio interface technology** (Firewire, Thunderbolt, ...) could be used to **let a DAW** use **individual channels on a mixer**? Does the mixer have to be **digital** in order to have that feature?

Maybe someone can explain to me how a setup like this is done properly.

Thanks a lot in advance!

**Edit01:**
Maybe to be a bit more precise: My current understanding: I have a stereo mix of all my channels going via USB to my computer. At the same time I have Main Out (2x XLR) going to a second audio interface via 6.3 jack. So I can record a max of 4 channels at the same time. I have REAPER and FL Studio.

If we ignore that part completely, the important part of the question is: "**Which connector** to **use all channels of a mixer individually**? I'm willing to spend around 600 bucks on a new one if necessary.

Comment: Yes they make 4+ channel USB interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I have various audio interfaces (there are plenty on the market) and all of mine can use upwards of 16 channels individually (or linked as 8 stereo channels if I need)

These interfaces take analogue inputs (and mine also have midi and a few other useful inputs)  and provide them to the PC through a digital channel.

USB audio interfaces work just fine, as do thunderbolt, firewire and others.

If you are just starting, buy an audio interface with more than the number of inputs than you need, and whatever your preferred connector is. I use USB, but if you have a Mac you may want Thunderbolt.

And the majority just work. DAW setup to use these interfaces is almost plug and play these days. The drivers should ensure they show up in the DAW interface selection, and you just need to assign them. On Cubase it took a couple of minutes. On Sonar the interface was picked up automagically.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply.
I have a Win10 x64 with an i7 and 32GB of RAM. My first AI was a Behringer 302 (tiny thing, not useful for a lot of things). Afterwards I bought the Behringer X1222USB. 16 Channels, but only a 2-Bus-Mix for USB.
Now I'm eyeing the Presonus StudioLive AR16 USB. According to Thomann it can use individual channels via ASIO.

Comment: I have FL Studio, REAPER and Studio One. I thought about Cubase once, but it seemed a bit hard to get into (Switching over from FL Studio).

Answer (score 0):

The Behringer X1222 is a 16-channel analogue mixer with a 2-channel USB interface built in.

The Presonus AR16 can output all channels via USB:

> Connect a StudioLive AR16 USB mixer to your computer via USB 2.0, and you have an 18x4 multitrack digital recorder,

your questions:

> What audio interface technology (Firewire, Thunderbolt, ...) could be used to let a DAW use individual channels on a mixer?

Any of them. Firewire used to be popular in the early days because computers were slow enough that multichannel audio via USB could lead to problems (FW data transmission causes less processor load than USB data transfer). These days, that's less of an issue (my Behringer X32 outputs all 32 channels via USB).

> Does the mixer have to be digital in order to have that feature?

No. You can get analog mixers where the AD conversion for USB takes place at the "end" of each channel strip (after the fader). I think the Presonus AR16 does this.